# After yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-lt on guest CentOS on VirtualBox in Windows 10 the clipboard no longer works

Tags: virtualbox, centos, clipboard

What actually can break the work of bidirectional clipboard exchange from guest CentOS 7 to Windows 10 on VirtualBox 5.1 after I execute in guest machine

```
sudo yum install https://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm

sudo yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-lt

sudo nano /etc/grub.conf
```

To set `default=0` in `/etc/grub.conf`. And then restart the machine like this:

```
shutdown -r now
```

What exactly prevents clipboard from working, since the guest addons are still there and it was working just before that actions.

I have reinstalled the Extension pack, that doesn't help.

After the kernel update I have several versions to be able to load in grub, like that:

[image]

So if the default one (the older one) is loaded, the bidirectional clipboard works. If I select the new kernel that is on the top, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you reinstall the Virtual Box guest extensions to see if that restores clipboard functionality.

Comment: I agree with John: Reinstall the [extension pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_1) and see what happens.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I have updated the question with the details

Comment: @John I have updated the question with the details

Comment: If feasible, back up your documents and consider reinstalling Centos. There may have been a change in extension functionality because of kernel change.

Comment: Also consider using the older kernel until the situation clarifies in some way